# Does System.Cryptography.Cng works in Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I've been trying to use `ECDiffieHellmanCng` from the nuget `System.Cryptography.Cng` and I was able to make it work for a console app trageting .netcore 3.1. However when I used it in a (windows) Azure function targeting 3.1 , I'm having a `PlatformNotSupportedException`. Looking at [ms docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.ecdiffiehellmancng?view=net-6.0) it seems to be supported? Am I missing something?

Comment: The docs show that the class is available for .NET 6 and unavailable for 3.1

Comment: In the "Applies to" section, you can see 3.1, in the .NET Platform extensions.

Comment: However, if you select .NET 3.1 in the left column it says **The requested page is not available for .NET Core 3.1.**

Comment: Anyway, I was able to solve it, it turns out, I had to downgrade the package version to 4.7 to make it work.

Comment: Please provide the solution as answer, so that it will help other community members facing similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the version of the package I'm using. It turns out the latest version at the time of writing is 5.0 which is not compatible in Azure Functions targeting .net core 3.1, though 5.0 works in console app having the same target. Downgrading `System.Cryptography.Cng` to 4.7 worked.